# Using svm and nnet for satellite image classification

Tags: r, classification, svm, nnet, satellite-image

I'm trying to run a satellite image classification using Support Vector Machine (svmPoly) and Neural Network (nnet). When running the cross-validation, I get the desired outputs (i.e. a 6x6 confusion matrix) from both methods. When I run the classification on the entire data set only SVM produces the multiclass (6 discrete classes) image output while nnet produces an image output with a single class.

```html
Here, is the code I'm using in R

## Creating a data Partition, which splits the data into 70% for training and 30% for testing
data_partition <- createDataPartition(training_table$layer, times= 100,  p= 0.7, list= FALSE)
data_train <- training_table[data_partition,] ## Training data
data_test <- training_table[-data_partition,] ## Testing data

## Defining training control parameters
control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=5, repeats=100, savePredictions="final", verboseIter=TRUE, classProbs=FALSE)

## Creating list of models to use
algorithmList <- c('svmPoly', 'nnet')

## Training the models
set.seed(50)
models <- caretList(factor(class) ~ a+b+c+d+e+f , data=data_train, trControl=control, methodList=algorithmList)

## Using the models created to predict the LULC classes of the Testing data 
preds <- as.data.frame(predict(object= models, data_test))

## Creating confusion matrix to check the accuracy of the prediction made by the different models wrt Testing data 
cm_svm <- confusionMatrix(preds$svmPoly, data_test$layer)
cm_nn <- confusionMatrix(preds$nnet, data_test$layer)

## Print confusion matrix
print(cm_svm)
print(cm_nn)

## Image Classification
## Training models using different methods
set.seed(50)
img_train_svm <- ksvm(class ~ a+b+c+d+e+f, data= training_table, type= "C-svc", kernel= "polydot", degree= 3, scale= 0.1, C= 1)
set.seed(50)
img_train_nn <- nnet(class ~ a+b+c+d+e+f, data= training_table, size = 5)

## Using different methods for classification 
img_class_svm <- predict(study_area, img_train_svm, fun= predict, na.rm=TRUE, progress="text")
img_class_nn <- predict(study_area, img_train_nn, fun= predict, na.rm=TRUE, progress="text")

## Viewing classification 
plot(img_class_svm, col= c("yellow", "red","brown", "green", "blue", "black"), main= 'SVM')
plot(img_class_nn, col= c("yellow", "red","brown", "green", "blue", "black"), main= 'NNet')
```

These are the output from the classification 
[Classification using svmPoly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJ6YF.png)
[Classification using nnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hK0P.png)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone point out the obvious?

Comment: In the call to the neural net `img_class_nn <- predict(...`, does adding the argument `type = "class"` help?

Comment: i've tried that but it doesnt work. the output looks like a probability output  and i'm wondering if theres some classification parameter that should be set but can't find one.

Comment: perhaps try estimating the hyper parameters first. nnet has size and decay that can be tuned in caret. In most cases `svmRadial` has the upper hand over  `svmPoly`. Also why are you doing 100 repeats of 5 - fold CV? especially if you are just doing the default search of length 3?

Comment: I used the tuning parameters from the cross-validation- size, decay and even played around with other parameters but still no success. Between Radial and Poly, is there any paper I could read up to justify choice? Could you please elaborate on the "default search of length 3"? I'm not sure I understand you.

Comment: Here are some answers I googled about RBF vs Polynomial kernel: [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110347/when-do-kernel-based-method-perform-better-than-the-regular), [2](https://www.quora.com/Machine-Learning/How-does-one-decide-on-which-kernel-to-choose-for-an-SVM-RBF-vs-linear-vs-poly-kernel). My knowledge of SVM is quite limited. As for the the question at hand - what were the best hyper parameters for the `nnet`? Could you provide part of the data and full code that brought you to the prediction?

Comment: thank you for the answers regarding the kernels but its not a journal and I can't use it for justification of kernel selection. I think cross validation is the only way to go around this. The code provided is the full code with the exception of data input.  The formula- class ~ a+b+c+d+e+f, here the values of class is 1,2,3,4,5,6 and each class has associated values of a,b,c,d,e,f. Values of a,b, and c ranges from 1 to 2000 while values of d ranges from -1 to +1, values of e ranges from 0.0 to 220.00 and values of f ranges from 1 to 1200.

Comment: the parameters from the cross validation Fitting size = 5, decay = 0.1